# Подсчет времени

Tags: c

Нужно осуществить ввод секунд и показать, сколько часов, минут и секунд содержится двумя видами: или часы:минуты:секунды, или Часов - Х, Минут - Х, Секунд - Х. Как это сделать?

Comment: @extazys, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу, так что расскажите что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Используйте strftime, например:

```
char formatted[9] = { 0 };

time_t actual;
struct tm *local;

time(&actual);
local = localtime(&actual);

strftime(formatted, sizeof(formatted), "%H:%M:%S", local);
puts(formatted);
```